# htaccess redirect

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess

I am hosting an application made using zend framework. and I have .htaccess file on public folder to redirect all request to pass through index.php. It is working but I do not get request parameters in application. Why is this?

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|txt|gif|GIF|jpg|png|PNG|css|xml|JPG)$ 

index.php
```

Comment: How are you determining that you aren't receiving request parameters? Can you post an example request and the code you're expecting to work?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a very robust solution. What happens when a request is made to a file extension not included in your list?

The standard ZF 1.11 rules are much better

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: @Vir What's the error message? It'll be in your Apache error log.

Comment: RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php  [NC,L]
 still not getring request parameter

Comment: @Vir 1) That's not an error message, and 2) You usually need a good reason to add `RewriteBase`. Why are you adding it?

Comment: Otherwise i get The requested URL /index/auth was not found on this server. error

Answer (score 1):

This will pass ALL requests excluding the file types listed to index.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(js|ico|txt|gif|GIF|jpg|png|PNG|css|xml|JPG)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://domain.com/index.php$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Also, if you are wanting to shorten your urls, perhaps try doing this:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ /index.php?p=$1`